# Is there a way to enable latency-monitor-threshold in Redis on AWS (ElastiCache)?

Tags: performance, redis, monitor, latency, amazon-elasticache

I would like to enable redis latency monitor for our managed Redis instances in AWS.
These are the official details on latency monitor from Redis: 
https://redis.io/topics/latency-monitor

Unfortunately, I cannot see the `latency-monitor-threshold` choice when creating a Parameter Group in AWS.